# OpenCV-2.4.4 POM entry Tag

Tags: maven, opencv, pom.xml

I am starting OpenCV in Java and want to get started by creating a maven project.
For that I am using **OpenCV-2.4.4** jar.

But was not able to find out the **pom entry** needed for that jar to be included in the **dependency**.

Tell me if I am missing something too trivial. Or where to find the POM entry for the same.
All I was able to find was the pom entry for the google version:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.javacv</groupId>
      <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
      <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
      <version>0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I need the pom tag for OpenCV-2.4.4.jar

Comment: In the mean time this bug is solved, i created my own entry tag and added the jar to the local repository.
**mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>**

Answer (score 6):

as far as I can see from the http://code.google.com/p/javacv/#Quick_Start_for_OpenCV_and_FFmpeg you should:

> point your pom.xml file to the Maven repository
>   http://maven2.javacv.googlecode.com/git/, and make sure that the
>   library files of OpenCV and FFmpeg (*.so, *.dylib, or *.dll) can be
>   found either in their default installation directories or in the
>   system library PATH, which under Windows includes the current working
>   directory.

To add new maven repo, you can follow:
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-remote-repository-in-maven-pom-xml/

afterwards, it seems you can go for the latest version of javacv (present in repo):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.javacv</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

or maybe, as you specified (with platform specific classifier):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.javacv</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
    <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE**:

Sorry, I seem to miss the point with my previous answer. If you're trying to go with the `OpenCV` java bindings rather than `JavaCV` (http://code.google.com/p/javacv), there seems to be no maven packaging provided yet.

As the official tutorial uses `ant` only (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html)

Moreover there is an open bug for what you expect: http://code.opencv.org/issues/3097

So the only option seem to be wait for resolution of the bug and use another way in the meanwhile.

Comment: i am not using javacv from google, rather i am using the one from OPENCV.ORG

Answer (score 1):

I know OpenCV developers are working to make a public maven repository for Java bindings, but I've made an example that shows how to do it, pretty much like Java OpenGL deals with it.

The full example can be retrieved from:
https://github.com/JavaOpenCVBook/code/tree/master/chapter1/maven-sample

Remember to add the github repository, as pointed by:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">  
     <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>javaopencvbook</id>
      <url>https://raw.github.com/JavaOpenCVBook/code/maven2/</url>
    </repository>  </repositories>

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> … </project>
```

For now, there are only windows 64 and 32 native jars available, but it should be easy to add your Linux/MacOS version of it.

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Update: there is also a 64 bit osx native file there as well.

Comment: Hi. Can I ask you a question? I'm using your dependencies. But when I get to this point: System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); I get:  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java247 in java.library.path] with root cause (or whatever opcencv-java*). How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Tupac, please, follow the instructions at: https://github.com/JavaOpenCVBook/code . Specifically, in Eclipse, check your referenced libraries and look for opencvjar-3.0.0 or opencvjar-2.4.7 and right click it -> Properties -> Native library -> Workspace -> Point it to the native file location, e.g.: maven-sample/target/natives

Comment: Thanks. that is a the way that should be done. I put the ".dll" in java/bin/

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well, but should be easier to point to maven natives in case there are updates. Actually, this is some standard way to point to native files. You can also update your POM to opencv 3.0, in windows, now.

Comment: well, thank you very much. Yes, I tried with 3.0 but, my Core.circle was broken, I don't wasted time, and I continue to use 2.4.9. I need to search what happend to that.